# How to delete a folder with space in the name(Golang)

Tags: path, go

The following codes works in windows:

```
//suppose I have a fname folder in c:\temp
mydir := "C:\\temp\\dname"
cmd, e := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", " rmdir /S /Q", mydir).Output()
```

But it will failed if there are spaces in the folder name, like:

```
mydir := "C:\\temp\\name with space"
```

The Golang `os.RemoveAll` can handle the folder name with spaces, but it will fail  in the following situation:

```
C:\> mkdir myprj
C:\> cd myprj
C:\myprj> git init
//add some file
C:\myprj> git add .
C:\myprj> git commit -m "Add my files"
//
//This won't work
err := os.RemoveAll("C:/myprj")
```

Any ideas on how to remove a folder completely in windows using Go?

### Update 1

Either `\\` or `/`is the same error:

```
func main() {
    if e := os.RemoveAll("c:\\temp\\myprj"); e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
}
//OUTPUT
remove c:\temp\myprj\.git\objects\2b\018ef36e172ae05842a9326fc73f1c8baa3254: Access is denied.
```

But I can delete the folder with this command:

```
C:\> rmdir /S /Q c:\temp\myprj
// or from windows file explore without any problem
```

Comment: The `RemoveAll` code looks close; I'm not on Windows, but maybe if you post the specific error RemoveAll gets, someone who knows more can debug. (You might also want to try RemoveAll but with `"C:\\..."` instead of `"C:/..."`.)

Comment: Could the problem be that the directory you're trying to delete is also the current directory of your command prompt? (i.e., you're trying to delete `c:\myprj` while you're in `c:\myprj`) I've had problems like that in the Unixy world.

Comment: do you have the permissions to delete the directory ? is the file read only ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Every file in `.git\objects` folder is Read-Only. But I can run `rmdir` to delete them without any problem. Also I run the code outside the `c:\myprj` folder.

Comment: Tip: always use forward slash `/` in Go source code. Windows understands this because it is Posix compliant. Your strings will be simpler if you never need double-backslash \\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method works well:

1. Create a batch file `myrmdir.bat`:

   `@echo off
   RMDIR /S /Q %1`
2. Place this file in the same folder as the code and call it with:

   `//Yes, I can use / instead of \\ and it works
   myfolder := "c:/temp/folder with space" 
   exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "myrmdir.bat", myfolder).Run()`

Hope this helps you. If you have a better solution(esp. pure Golang solution) please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing on my windows and got the same error too. But I noticed the myprj folder is readonly (in properties) so I turned it off then the code works.

Actually every folder I created on c:\ is "readonly" by default.

And this is not apply to an empty folder the properties says "Read-Only (Only applies to files in folder)".

Comment: Even if I turned off the readonly property on folder `c:\myprj`, but if I `git commit` something, there will be read only files in `.git\objects` folder. Is there any way to make `exec.Command` work with spaces in the folder name, so I can use `rmdir` to remove all files. Or is there any way to remove the Readonly property in Golang?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t read the first part of OP very carefully. This should work: attrib -R C:\temp  http://play.golang.org/p/dbdfYDjpN-

Comment: Thanks. It should be `exec.Command("cmd","/C","attrib -R","C:\\any foler with space")`, but it still won't work with the space inside. Actually I've found a work around to do this as following answers.